# How do i integrate jhipster with Stormpath

Tags: jhipster, stormpath

I am trying to use jhipster. The sample works nice out of the box.

I want to configure it to use Stormpath User management - https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-spring-security/wiki

I could not find any blog/article on ensuring the Spring Server and AngularJS  Client both use StormPath.

Answer (score 0):

check this out-> [JHipster sub-generator](https://stormpath.com/blog/stormpath-jhipster-application).

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this fork. i used it in my project and it works quite good.
  https://github.com/moifort/generator-jhipster/tree/user-managment

Comment: I need a bit more guidance. Newbie alert. I cloned to my machine. Checkout the branch. I did a grep for stormpath. No results. If there is no template for stormpath, how does this work?